# How to use SVG images for Xamarin.Forms application?

Tags: xamarin.forms, nuget

It seems it's possible to some extent to use SVG images in some controls, for instance SVG files can be only added as embedded resources when using some of the available NuGet packages out there. Also, at least for `ToolbarItem` the images need to be stored somewhere in the file system, so I had to create my own SVG rasterizer that saves those images to bitmaps in the cache directory, so those could be passed in a `FileImageSource` to the `Icon` property in the control `ToolbarItem`. For, the control `Button` those images need to be stored in the Resources or drawable directory, so it won't work with the rasterized bitmaps, since those are stored in the cache directory. With all those limitations when trying to use SVG files directly at runtime, I was thinking maybe I could convert all those images to the corresponding JPG or PNG images at build time using some task, but I'm not sure whether that conversion could be done with the current available tools. So, my questions is how to use convert directly SVG images for using in common controls in a Xamarin.Forms application (`ToolbarItem`, `Button`, etc)?

Comment: Have you found any solution for this yet?

Comment: @Shaw Yes! ...using [this](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Resizetizer/) NuGet package.